# Composer: can I ask for requirement alternatives?

Tags: composer-php

With Composer, I can display an error before the installation if all the requirements are not met.

But can I tell it to chose between two alternatives ?

For instance, I want to use image manipulation on my project. I have to check whether gd2 or imageMagick are present. But if I list them both in my require key, an error will be thrown if I don't have both of them.

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-imagick": "*"
  },
}
```

How can I tell Composer it may use `gd` OR `imagick` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. See https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/751 and https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2940 for some more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.